# How to JOIN based on OR condition from one table to multiple tables?

Tags: sql

I need to do the following logic. I have to pick `t2.demandGroup`.

IF

`t1.localShipToParty = t2.customerId` then `t2.demandGroup`

ELSE

`t1.localShipToParty = t3.kunnr` if yes then check

`t3.hkunnr = t2.customerId` for corresponding record, if yes, then `t2.demandGroup`

SAMPLE FIDDLE: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fM9XU115zMux2hkdsLEiz2/0

Example:

```
    select * from t1;

| localShipToParty |
| ---------------- |
| 123              |
| 0000170249       |
| 783947           |

    select * from t2;

| customerId | demandGroup |
| ---------- | ----------- |
| 123        | grp1        |
| 0000000341 | grp2        |

    select * from t3;

| kunnr      | hkunnr     |
| ---------- | ---------- |
| 0000170249 | 0000000341 |
```

Desired output:

```
| demandGroup |
| ----------- |
| grp1        |
| grp2        |
```

Following solution works:

```
select t2.demandGroup
from t1
inner join t2
on t1.localShipToParty = t2.customerId

UNION

select t2.demandGroup
from t1
inner join t3
on t1.localShipToParty = t3.kunnr
inner join t2
on t3.hkunnr = t2.customerId;
```

My question is whether I can do the above solution without a `UNION` ie with an `OR` condition maybe? I ask for a better solution than a `UNION` because the remaining query is around 2000 lines long and I would like to avoid copy pasting just relevant parts with a `UNION` to avoid confusion. If I copy paste for the `UNION` I would get close to 10000 lines of code.

Something like this

```
select t2.demandGroup
from t1
( inner join t2
  on t1.localShipToParty = t2.customerId
) OR 
( inner join t3
  on t1.localShipToParty = t3.kunnr
  inner join t2
  on t3.hkunnr = t2.customerId
)
```

NOTE: I am not querying from an RDBMS, but rather from a grid. So I would appreciate a vendor agnostic solution. Also, the example in the DB-Fiddle is for illustrative purpose (MySQL 8.0).

EDIT:

As per the comment, I tried using two `left outer join`. But I am not getting the desired output.

```
    select t2.demandGroup as output
    from t1
    left outer join t2
    on t1.localShipToParty = t2.customerId
    left outer join t3
    on t1.localShipToParty = t3.kunnr
    and t3.hkunnr = t2.customerId;

| output |
| ------ |
| grp1   |
|        |
|        |
```

Comment: Two `[outer] left join`'s. The joins that don't match will have null values in columns.

Comment: @user2864740 can you please explain more with an answer?

Comment: @user2864740 I tried your solution. Edited the question. It does not give the desired output though.

Comment: @user2864740 is really close. The version you added to the question is missing the `COALESCE`, which is where the magic is. I'd take another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use two LEFT JOIN operations. OUTER JOINs include null values in columns for unmatched rows.

```
-- select result from t3x or t2
select coalesce(t3x.demandGroup, t2.demandGroup) as demandGroup
from t1
-- if "true", t2 columns contain values
left join t2
on t1.localShipToParty = t2.customerId
-- if "true", t3x columns contain values
left join (
   -- maybe it makes sense to rename for consistency, maybe it doesn't
   select t3.kunnr as customerId, t2.demandGroup
   from t3
   inner join t2
   on t3.hkunnr = t2.customerId) t3x
on t1.localShipToParty = t3x.customerId
where coalesce(t3x.demandGroup, t2.demandGroup) is not null;
```

Comment: Your answer works on my test data on the fiddle, but it also gives the null values as records in the output.

Comment: Maybe the production data matches neither..?

Comment: Hi I have tested on my production data, and your solution works. Thank you very much. I have also added to your answer, the logic in the `where` clause for removing the `null` from `coalesce`. Thank you very much for your help. Marking it as correct.

Comment: @scientific_explorer Thanks for updating my answers to generate correct output per the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Horrible way to get the result :) due to cartezian joins first and then filtering result but that seems one of the way.

```
select * from 
(
    select   t1.* ,t2.*,t3.*
    from t2 
    left outer join t1 on 1=1 
    left outer join t3 on 1=1
) 
where demandGroup is not null and (
(localShipToParty=kunnr and hkunnr=customerId) or
(localShipToParty =customerId ))

;
```